# Package and class scope rules?

Tags: java, scope, package

I am writing a Java program that is divided into packages.
How do I give permission to class in the scope that is defined in it, and to its sub-scopes.

For example, I have 3 packages app.A, app.A.Sub, app.B. And in packge A I have class GlobalA.
I want that only package app.A and app.A.Sub will be able to use GlobalA, but app.B cant use it.

How can I do it?

Comment: People voting to close as not a real question, it seems pretty obvious what OP is asking.

Comment: @Woot4Moo I didn't vote but the problem is that the language used (sub-scope, "A, SubA") makes it very hard to be sure of the question.

Comment: Probably the assumed "hirarchy" comes through the dots in the package names. That, however, is only naming and not relevant for anything related to access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is absolutely no hierarchy in java packages. There are just names.

So package `a.suba` and `a` have no special relation. You have no way to give special rights to "sub packages".

Comment: No you definitely can restrict access to a class

Comment: @dystroy - My comment was addressed to the comment by Jarrod Roberson (which comment is now deleted, so I'll delete mine). By the way, now that you deleted the part about not being able to restrict access to classes, your answer earns a +1 from me.

Comment: This is the correct answer. a.sub.MyClass can't restrict  b.YourClass from using something AND allow a.OtherClass to.

Answer (score 0):

The rules of [access modifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

```
    Modifier    Class   Package     Subclass    World
    public      Y   Y   Y   Y
    protected   Y   Y   Y   N
    no modifier Y   Y   N   N
    private     Y   N   N   N
```

Based on the rules above you want GlobalA to be the default (no modifier) access.  Which will prevent B and anything not inside the packageA from seeing it.  Now it should be known when you declare a .java file you do need something to have a public modifier attached to an Object that has the same name as the .java file.  I.e.  public class Foo resides in Foo.java

Comment: But no modifier block the access to GlobalA from SubA

Comment: Has to be in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

Since both `SubA` and `B` are "foreign" packages to `A`, and since everything you allow or forbid by access modifiers applies to all "foreign" packages in a similar way, it seems to me logically impossible to distiguish between `SubA` and `B` by simply using access modifiers.

It's probably possible by using reflection, but I do not think it's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not really use the model of sub-packages in the language; it's only a convenient way to organize related code. That is, if you have packages `a`, `a.b` and `b` (where, in your terminology, `a.b` is a "subpackage" of `a`), then you can't do anything with the access modifiers of classes in package `a` that affects code in packages `a.b` and `b` in different ways. As far as Java is concerned, `a.b` and `b` will have exactly the same access rights to classes in `a`.